# Compositor. How to join two composite nodes?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I'm rather a bit new to the whole node editor and have set up two node sets. One for a glow and one for a focus. I want to combine the two, here they are:
[image]

You see the two composite nodes? I want to make those into one whole composition so it renders the glow AND defocus, not one or the other. Thanks!

Comment: Use a mix node, hit shift A; then press search type mix, then have the two outputs from the glare and the defocus go into the input of the node.

Comment: I did that and at first it turned white, so I turned down the fac and it's showing only the glare node. The defocus isn't showing up.

Comment: There should be only one composite node (that will be your final output). There are many ways to combine the processed image, you It would help if you added more information on your question about your goal. Basically you have to decide what kind of operation you want to use to combine the two images.  A mix node is one of the possible way to do this, and depending on the result you are after you can use different modes like add, multiply mix or use any of the other ways to combine images. Read: https://www.blender.org/manual/en/compositing/types/color/mix.html

Comment: A different option would be to serialize the node operations, but again, it's hard to guess what you want to do.

Comment: My goal is to have it focus only on Godzilla, and also to have a glow to the thing. The focus is achieved with the defocus node and the glow is achieved with the glare node. So I want both nodes to go in the same composite node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could chain the two nodes together. So the defocus node goes into the glare node, which goes into composite. Delete one of the render layers nodes.